# Removing top left panel of embedded google map

Tags: html, google-maps

I'm embedding a google map with a marker on it using the embed feature whereby i'm given the URL below. My problem is that the top left panel encroaches too much and I would like to remove or contract it. I this possible? I have seem somewhere that introducing "output=embed" somewhere into the url helps but I can't get anything to happen in this example..

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d48862.31335129727!2d-1.763692!3d53.701791!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x2c8856d4951c5657!2sFrederick+Crowther+and+Son+Ltd!5e1!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1421754685023" width="469" height="345" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

You would need to use the google maps api.
This definitely does allow you to choose which default google maps controls to show and hide.

It's not very difficult to use the api. Here is a good [tutorial](http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/) on setting a basic map with markers.

Here is a [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI) to hiding controls or using custom ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will look into those methods